# Docker-compose extra_hosts on Mac

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose, hosts

I'm trying to add a new hosts to my Nginx container with the extra_hosts configuration of Docker-compose. For some reason, I can't make it work. I'm using Docker for Mac 17.06 CE stable with Docker-Compose v3. Here's my configuration:

```
nginx:
    build: ./docker/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}:/var/www/html:ro"
    networks:
      - server
    extra_hosts:
      - 'test.local:127.0.0.1'
    depends_on:
      - php
    restart: always
```

I also tried to add the extra host with my Mac inet IP but it does not respond too.

**UPDATE**

For some reason, you need to edit the /etc/hosts file of you're Mac to add a new host. The extra_hosts configuration does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need edit this file in your Mac: `/etc/sudoers`

Add this:

```
127.0.0.1 test.local
```

For instance:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 127.0.0.1 test.local >> /etc/hosts"
```

If it does not work, try this other file: `/private/etc/hosts`.

See: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/

Comment: Can you explain why does this file have anything to do with the problem? I tried it but only got a syntax error.

Comment: If you are trying to access this: `http://test.local` from your web browser, you need to tell your OSX to resolve that name to the `127.0.0.1` localhost ip. Maybe this could help: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thank you, it did work! You should update you're answer so it explain correctly that you have to edit the file /etc/hosts instead of the one you mentionned. I still don't get why I have to edit my machine host though.

Comment: Think that your web browser **asks** the operating system (OSX) for the IP of `test.local`. OSX won't ask docker anything related to it.

Comment: great answer.  In Windows you can find the hosts file at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.